# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not st

Tags: python

new to python and having trouble with this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests

symbols = 'https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'



for symbol in symbols:
    symbol = requests.get(symbols)
    symbol = symbol.json()
    print(symbol['symbol'])
```

Comment: It looks like you're expecting a dictionary from the JSON response but you're getting a list. Consider printing out `symbol` to see if it's the shape you're envisioning

Comment: symbol = requests.get(symbols) should be outside the for loop

Comment: You are setting symbols to a string value and then looping through each of the letters of the string. Instead, you should be doing something like what @Malay suggested, but you don't really need the json module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json module to convert the Response in Json Format. Check if this code gives the desired output.

```
import requests, json
url = 'https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
symbols = requests.get(url)
symbols = json.loads(symbols.text)
for symbol in symbols:
    print(symbol['symbol'])
```